# Android. Как создать ряд кнопок, чтоб если не влазили в экран, то переносились на новую строку?

Tags: android, xml, button

Мне нужно создать ряд кнопок(хоть xml, хоть программно), которые не влазят во всю ширину экрана, после этого мне нужно будет их скрывать, и они должны сдвигаться в лево заполняя пространство скрытой кнопки.
При этом не используя сторонних библиотек для такой простой задачи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая библиотека - [FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использовать так:

```
<com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start|top">

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum" />
  <!-- тут сколько угодно View-->

</com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не хочется утяжелять приложение дополнительной библиотекой ради такой простой задачи, уверен это как то решается стандартными способами.

Comment: @Gennady, не надо бояться зависимости добавлять. Можно, конечно и велосипед свой написать... А вообще - в ответе - цели дубля, в конце, есть ссылка на гугловый компонент из либы поддержки, коий тоже это умеет. Возьмите его, если этот не нравится.